# Open CRM in a jquery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, dynamics-crm

Is there a trick to getting a Microsoft Dynamic CRM page to load in a jquery UI dialog, it appears that AD authentication does not happen and a 401 is returned. Opening the site via window.open does authenticate.

```
$("#dialog").load(href).dialog({ modal: true });
```

Comment: what crm page? where is your code? we will need more information than this.

Comment: any crm page or sharepoint page. Basically any page that is AD authenticated, and its url is passed in. ex. $("#dialog").load("http:/mycrmsite").dialog({ modal: true });

Comment: Ohhhh you mean "OpenCRM" not "CRM"? as "CRM" is Customer Relationship Management, and is very ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way it would authenticate is if we used an iframe, and we were forced to go that route.